# Is recommending software to replace the code the OP is trying to write actually an answer?

Tags: discussion

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28281176/1986871) basically says *hey, don't bother writing your own C++ code to search for a string in a file. Grep already exists!*

Oddly enough, it's getting upvotes. Doesn't this fall under the *not an answer* category? Because it's really not, and I flagged it as such.

Is recommending software to replace the code the OP is trying to write actually an answer? Is the SO community just upvoting because (using Grep) is the obvious thing to do?

**Edit**: It is unclear whether or not the OP is actually trying to practice C++ code and just stumbling, or just accidentally trying to re-write `grep`. That's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: I think it depends on the context. I usually go both ways - I tell about a more obvious answer and I try to answer the question as OP originally intended. Re-inventing the wheel is fun, but sometimes it is a lot of wasted effort.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment that it's not an answer.  That looks like an answer to me. Not an Answer would be stuff like `thanks` or `I like turtles`. This is directing the user to a possible solution to their problem.

Comment: @bluefeet Possibly, possibly not. The OP didn't really give any context. I don't know whether he's just trying to practice writing C++ code, or legitimately trying to re-invent the wheel (unaware of the existence of `grep`). That's why I posted this question; perhaps my flag was wrong.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice If the user doesn't provide context; then the question may deserve downvotes.  A bad question can beget bad answers, but that's not a fault of the answer, but of the question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker It is the fault of *both* users if someone posts a bad answer to a bad question.  When you see a bad question you should not answer it (and ideally help the author improve it), rather than post a bad answer.  Of course, an answer that doesn't answer the question because the question is vague and unclear shouldn't be flagged/deleted, just downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is recommending software to replace the code the OP is trying to write actually an answer?

Yes.  If it's just a product name alone it's probably a fairly low quality answer, but it's not "Not An Answer".  For it to be a quality answer it should not only provide the product, but show how to to use it to solve the problem at hand, and provide any information that might be relevant in using the product in this case.  The answer you provided does this; it explains not just what product to use, but why it should be used to solve this problem.

Product recommendations as answers *might* be spam, if someone is going around posting the same product recommendation all over, or if they don't disclose an affiliation.  I see no evidence that this specific answer is spam at all.

Comment: What I'm gathering from this: without knowing what the OP is actually trying to do, (practice coding or accidentally trying to rewrite an existing product due to lack of awareness), 'product answers' are okay. If the OP said "I'm just trying to practice my C++ skills", would `grep` still be a valid answer?

Comment: @ChrisCirefice If someone posted a question saying, "I'm trying to re-implement grep to learn how it works, I have [...], and its giving me this problem [...]" and then an answer is posted that says, "use grep" then it's not "Not An Answer", it's just an answer that fails to answer the question.  It would be no different than posting an incorrect answer.  Go ahead and downvote it for basically being wrong.  It doesn't merit deletion though; there's no reason at all to flag it.

Comment: Well I suppose that I completely misused the flag then, my bad. I suppose that yes, it technically *does* answer the question, just in a poor way imo. I'll be more careful about flags next time, thanks.